# Why is $S(\omega)=S(\omega +2\pi)$ true for a frequency spectrum?

Tags: frequency, fourier-transform

I [reviewed some notes on spectral decomposition](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/46343/14-384Fall-2007/NR/rdonlyres/Economics/14-384Fall-2007/C44EDBD5-F97A-4E7A-8C3F-1335E7A83CC4/0/lec4.pdf), and while I understand the maths behind it, I don't know how to physically interpret

$S(\omega)=S(\omega +2\pi)$.

Does that mean that in any kind of signal, the intensity associated with the frequency, say, 5Hz ($\omega = 10\pi$) is the same as the intensity associated with 6Hz:

$S(5Hz)=S(\omega = 10\pi) = S(12\pi)=S(6Hz)$?

Of course I could now iteratively continue indefinitely and thus conclude that any signal's frequency spectrum has the same value for all multiples of 1Hz, which [cannot be the case](http://www.uh.edu/~jclarage/astr3131/lectures/8/Chaisson_Fig.3.11%20blackbody.jpg).

Obviously I am making a blatant mistake in my interpretation, but where?

Comment: It's only true for a function defined on a grid of points with distance of $1$, as $\gamma_j$ defined for $j\in\mathbb Z$ in your link. For a function defined on $\mathbb R$ this isn't true. In general, you should substitute $2\pi$ with $2\pi/a$ for a grid with period $a$.

Comment: First of all, it makes very little sense to add $\omega$ (a frequency) and $2\pi$ (a dimensionless number). You can do it if you have a dimensionless frequency (i.e. if you're measuring with respect to some specified reference frequency), but not if you're trying to compare Hz vs $\pi$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relationship $S(\omega)=S(\omega+2\pi/T)$, which you can simplify to $S(\omega)=S(\omega+2\pi)$ if you have some reference timescale $T$ to compare to, **is false in the general case**. It should be intuitively clear that the arbitrary function has an arbitrary Fourier transform, which means that in general it won't obey this periodicity condition.

The notes you linked to use this relationship because they are constraining themselves exclusively to the case of a time series: the time-domain waveform is a series of delta spikes at regular intervals, and it is zero in between. This time series comes with a natural timescale, the separation $T$ between the spikes, which you can then set to $1$ as the notes have done.

In this case, the time-domain waveform has the form
$$
f(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \gamma_n\delta(t-nT), \tag 1
$$
and this form is what constrains the spectrum. The spectrum is in general given by a definition of the form
$$
S(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-i\omega t}\mathrm dt.\tag 2
$$
If you plug in the explicit time-series form $(1)$ for $f(t)$, you get 
$$
S(\omega) =  \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \gamma_n e^{-in\omega T}, \tag 3
$$
and here you can see that the spectrum is periodic in $\omega$, with period $2\pi/T$:
\begin{align}
S(\omega+2\pi/T)
   & =  \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \gamma_n e^{-in\left(\omega+\frac{2\pi}{T}\right) T}
\\ & =  \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \gamma_n e^{-in\omega T} e^{-2\pi n i}
\\ & =  \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \gamma_n e^{-in\omega T}
\\ & = S(\omega).
\end{align}

In essence, you're taking the same situation as a Fourier series (where if your time domain is bounded, with a periodic function on top, the Fourier dual is a Fourier series instead of a transform - a discrete series instead of a continuous spread), and looking at it 'backwards' by re-labelling the time and frequency domains as each other. This is an example of a [Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality) - you're on opposite corners of the basic quadrangle:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\begin{pmatrix}
\text{Fourier transform}\\
t\color{blue}{\text{ unbounded}}\text{  and }\color{blue}{\text{continuous}}\\
\omega\color{blue}{\text{ unbounded}}\text{  and }\color{blue}{\text{continuous}}
\end{pmatrix}
& & 
\begin{pmatrix}
\text{Fourier series}\\
t\color{green}{\text{ bounded}}\text{  and }\color{blue}{\text{continuous}}\\
\omega\color{blue}{\text{ unbounded}}\text{  and }\color{green}{\text{discrete}}
\end{pmatrix}
\\ & & \\
\begin{pmatrix}
\text{Time series}\\
t\color{blue}{\text{ unbounded}}\text{  and }\color{green}{\text{discrete}}\\
\omega\color{green}{\text{ bounded}}\text{  and }\color{blue}{\text{continuous}}
\end{pmatrix}
& & 
\begin{pmatrix}
\text{Discrete Fourier transform}\\
t\color{green}{\text{ bounded}}\text{  and }\color{green}{\text{discrete}}\\
\omega\color{green}{\text{ bounded}}\text{  and }\color{green}{\text{discrete}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{array}
$$

(Here it is important to note that 'bounded' really means 'bounded and periodic' - i.e. the domain is really a circle, not a line segment, or a discrete subset of one.)

Because the time and frequency domains are essentially equivalent (i.e. because the Fourier transform and its inverse are essentially the same), these two opposite corners are essentially identical - they differ only in terms of which domain you call frequency and which domain you call time.

This means, then, that the fundamental answer to "why is my spectrum periodic?" is "because you've got a Fourier series and you're seeing it backwards".

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer! To follow up on your response: Does that mean that for "actual" time series that I measure - which will always be discrete, and bounded in time, I always use a DFT?  And thus my spectral analysis will always yield unbounded, discrete frequency components? However, I thought that a timeseries of finite length will always result in high frequency comoponents (that are unbounded). Obviously that's not true?

Comment: For any actual time series, you do always use a DFT. (Unless, that is, the time spacing changes, in which case you need slightly more refined tools.) In that case, the frequency domain is bounded and periodic (because the time domain is discrete), and it is also discrete (because the time domain is bounded). That is, you don't get new meaningful information from frequencies outside the optimal frequency sampling grid.